# Streaming values in a python script to a wep app

Tags: python, azure, web-applications, azure-webjobs

I have a python script that runs continuously as a WebJob (using Microsoft Azure), it generates some values (heart beat rate) continuously, and I want to display those values in my Web App.
I don't know how to proceed to link the WebJob to the web app.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main options:

You can have the WebJobs write the values to a database or to Azure Storage (e.g. a queue), and have the Web App read them from there.

Or if the WebJob and App are in the same Web App, you can use the file system. e.g. have the WebJob write things into %home%\data\SomeFolderYouChoose, and have the Web App read from the same place.

Comment: I had the first idea, but the number of times I will need to access the database would be huge, without taking into account the little delay each time.
So  I implemented the second option, and it works just great !
For the steps I took, the web job writes to the file, then from the html page and using jQuery.
 ` <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function() {
      $('#div1').load('heartBeat.php');
    }, 300);
  });
  </script>`
And the heartBeat.php just echoes the content of the file I am writing to.
Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide some more information about what kind of interface your web app exposes. Does it only handle normal HTTP1 requests or does it have a web socket or HTTP2 type interface? If it has only HTTP1 requests that it can handle then you just need to make multiple requests or try and do long polling. Otherwise you need to connect with a web socket and stream the data over a normal socket connection.

Comment: I can have a web socket, I am using an azure wep application.

Comment: So then you just need to decide what libraries you want to use. You could use Twisted or Tornado. You have a lot of options to look at. Both projects have a ton of documentation and examples.

Comment: Can you provide me with some resource that you think could help ? I can't seem to find whatI seek